# Is a change required only in the code of a web application to support HSTS?

Tags: https

If I want a client to always use a HTTPs connection, do I only need to include the headers in the code of the application or do I also need to make a change on the server? Also how is this different to simply redirecting a user to a HTTPs page make every single time they attempt to use HTTP?

Comment: Is the API web based? What is the client in this scenario?

Comment: @Ram - There is no API involved. For example I have a website that always requires a secure channel. The client is a web browser. Never really thought about other clients but would be keen to know which other instances allow for HSTS?

Comment: The main difference is that you trigger the client (if it has the feature) to not even try to use HTTP thus preventing them from sending valuables across HTTP in attempt to reach your server (who will not process it anyway). For the server side you have plenty of options at multiple levels: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Implementation

Comment: @Ram - I had a read of Wikipedia earlier and hence my post to confirm that it is only a code change. If so, how is this different to redirecting users to a HTTP page e.g. URL Rewrite, mod_rewrite, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have HTTP -> HTTPS redirects a client might still try to post sensitive data to you (or GET a URL that has sensitive data in it) - this would leave it exposed publicly. If it knew your site was HSTS then it would not even try to hit it via HTTP and so that exposure is eliminated. It's a pretty small win IMO - the bigger risks are the vast # of root CAs that everyone trusts blindly thanks to policies at Microsoft, Mozilla, Opera, and Google.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment `If you just have HTTP -> HTTPS redirects a client might still try to post sensitive data to you (or GET a URL that has sensitive data in it) - this would leave it exposed publicly.`

Comment: If the bigger risk is indeed the vast number of root Certificate Authorities, what would you recommend being a way around it?

Comment: With HTTPS a 'secure' tunnel is established before any other data is passed back and forth (request URI, cookies, POST data). In HTTP that stuff just comes over. If a browser knows that your site doesn't do HTTP it won't ever transmit those elements over HTTP and so it is harder for a bad guy to watch the traffic go by and read information contained in the initial group of packets sent.

Comment: Manage your root list by eliminating those that have week technical policies or those that you have reason not to trust. As your level of risk increases (say you do banking online) you should be less trusting. As your level of risk decreases you may be more trusting.

Comment: Thanks. So do you mean to say if I have a HTTP link that takes a user to a page that then redirects a user to a HTTPs page, information is susceptible to be viewed or misused during the HTTP handshake? Interesting. Never really thought about it.

Comment: The assumption of using HSTS is of course that the first communication occurs without a secure channel. Is that correct unless there is a HSTS database that is included with the browser? Where can I find such a database?

Comment: Assuming the link already contains the prefix https: is the secure tunnel established before any data is passed back?

Comment: IIRC Google does publish an HSTS list, maybe only in Chrome. If the HTTP link you hand out is unqualified (http://example.com but NOT http:///example.com/sensitive/data) then nothing is exposed but if there is sensitive data in the URL or the browser decides to post a form via HTTP then it can be seen en-route to the server. In HTTPS URLs the SSL negotiation happens first.